# Docker two containers two public IP , same Port

Tags: docker, networking, server, ip, containers

I have two public IP addresses in the same server eth0 and eth0:0.

And I have two containers that I would like them to listen on the same port but not on the same public address.
My two containers are attached to the docker0

that I have :

- eth0    =192.xx.xx.50
- eth0:0  =192.xx.xx.51
- container1  = 172.17.0.5 ---------> 192.xx.xx.50:443
- container2 = 172.17.0.6 ---------> 192.xx.xx.50:9443

what I want :

- eth0    =192.xx.xx.50
- eth0:0  =192.xx.xx.51
- container 1  = 172.17.0.5 ---------> 192.xx.xx.50:443
- container 2 = 172.17.0.6 ---------> 192.xx.xx.51:443

How should I proceed to find a solution?

1. create a new docker network? how to allocate it to the second
   ip address?
2. other solutions ?

THANKS

Comment: Looks like what you need is a reverse proxy like nginx, ha proxy, or traefik. As no matter what you can't have two processes with one port.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to map the internal container port to a `hostip:port` combination using `docker run -p ip:hostPort:containerPort ...etc...`

You dont specify the internal ports in your post, but assuming the application in your container is listening on port 8080, and you want to expose this publicly as 192.168.100.1:80 then you would do:

`docker run -p 192.168.100.1:80:8080 ...etc...`

(see https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports for details)

Comment: it wasnt clear from the question I think. Please post your compose file